# non-blocking thread-safe queue in C++?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

Is there a thread-safe, non-blocking queue class in the C++?

Probably a basic question but I haven't been doing C++ for a long time...

**EDIT:** removed STL requirement.

Comment: `boost::lockfree::queue` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming your CPU has a double-pointer-wide compare-and-swap (compxchg8b on 486 or higher, compxchg16b on most amd64 machines [not present on some early models by Intel])...  There is an algorithm [here](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/research/synchronization/pseudocode/queues.html).

Update: It's not hard to translate this to C++ if you aren't afraid of doing a bit of work.  :P

This algorithm assumes a "pointer with tag" structure which looks like this:

```
// Be aware that copying this structure has to be done atomically...

template <class T>
struct pointer
{
   T *ptr;
   uintptr_t tag;
};
```

Then you want to wrap the instructions `lock cmpxchg{8|16}b` with some inline asm...

Maybe then you can write the queue node like this:

```
template <class T>
struct queue_node
{
    T value;
    pointer<queue_node<T> > next;
};
```

The rest is more or less a transcription of the algorithm I linked to...

Comment: @jldupont: -1 is too harash for that.  Asveikau gave you a good link to an algorithm, and it takes just a few minutes to translate it to C++.  -1 is totally uncalled for here

Comment: ...that's why I haven't down-voted him... just gave him a mark.  If you look at my profile, you'll see I am very generous... you won't see lots of down-votes handed by me.

Comment: The hazard pointer based queue is another option - it allows free'ing unused memory back to the OS, instead of having to maintain it forever in a free list. http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/ieeetpds-2004.pdf Also see Relacy for sanity checking your lock free algorithm: http://groups.google.com/group/relacy

Comment: Why do you say -1 if you don't actually downvote? That's just confusing. :p

Comment: It's 2013 and C++ still doesn't have a standard thread-safe queue library? How many thousands of developers have had to write this same thing over again?

Answer (score 6):

Since the current C++ standard doesn't even acknowledge the existence of threads, there is most certainly nothing thread-safe in the STL or any other part of the standard library.

Comment: OK then: how about outside of STL?

Comment: Nothing that the standard guarantees will be thread-safe anyway. Real implementations can and do provide their own guarantees though.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to have been a popular subject on Dr. Dobb's last year:

- [Lock-Free Queues](http://www.ddj.com/hpc-high-performance-computing/208801974)
- [Writing Lock-Free Code: A Corrected Queue](http://www.ddj.com/hpc-high-performance-computing/210604448)

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement it yourself or use a library implementing it. To do it yourself, you may want to have a look at this:

[Implementing a Thread-Safe Queue using Condition Variables](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that would add another dependency to my project: boost library. No?

Comment: That's right. Anyway, you'll eventually use Boost if you're a C++ developer. Nikolai N Fetissov's suggestion about boost::mutex is a good one.

Comment: Being a C++ developer does not always lead to Boost.  I know everyone here seems to love it, but lots of projects get along with out it (and even ban it).  Have a look at how Chromium implements this.

Comment: Policy issues, no more no less.

Comment: A condition variable is always used in conjunction with a mutex. That doesn't fit with the question's requirement for a non-blocking queue.

Comment: @JerryCoffin web search seems to indicate that "non-blocking queue" can mean at least two different things: (1) no locking/blocking at all in the implementation, i.e. lock-free (2) `dequeue()` called on an empty queue will return a special value meaning "empty" rather than waiting for the queue to become nonempty.   I guess this answer assumes the latter.  No idea which one the OP intended to be asking about.

Answer (score 2):

May be too late now. For future reference, this one is a good implementation of lock-free queues (built in thread safety with some caveats).

Multi producer - Multi consumer

http://moodycamel.com/blog/2014/a-fast-general-purpose-lock-free-queue-for-c++

https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue

Single producer - Single consumer

http://moodycamel.com/blog/2013/a-fast-lock-free-queue-for-c++

https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue

Answer (score 1):

STL containers are not thread-safe, you should implement your treatment for concurrent access.
There is this project (C++) that aims to serve concurrent accesses : [CPH STL](http://www.cphstl.dk/WWW/downloads.html)
and [paper about](http://www.cphstl.dk/Report/Safe-containers/mini-project.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no. STL does not concern itself with concurrency (at least on the specification level.) Current C++ standard says nothing about threads.
You can easily build such a queue on top of STL and Boost though - just wrap `std::queue` and `boost::mutex` in your custom class.

Comment: is the boost normally packaged in the popular distributions e.g. Ubuntu, Fedora?

Comment: I think so, at least the vanilla RHEL installs at my job always have older Boost version under /usr/include that gets in way.

Comment: Keep in mind that the original question was about a *non-blocking* queue. A mutex is a way of blocking, so it's unlikely to qualify.

Comment: You can always try_lock and bail - no blocking here :)

Comment: "Current C++ standard"—can you update your answer in light of C++11?

Answer (score 0):

The currently unofficial [Boost.Lockfree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725827/lockfree-standard-collections-and-tutorial-or-articles/2183715#2183715) is something to consider. I use both the FIFO and the atomic types.

Answer (score 0):

Non blocking would mean without the need of any mutex, semaphore, critical section etc.

For a single producer and a single consumer, that is one thread pushes and the other pop elements, in my "strong" opinion a circular queue like the one provided below would be enough.

Here is the code together with comments about other possibilities

```
  // --------- class: TNQueue
  // 
  // Implements a fixed size circular queue which is non-blocking and thread safe provided that
  //
  //    - there is only one producer, that is one thread that pushes into the queue
  //    - and only one consumer, a thread that pops the queue
  //    - producer has to handle fullness of the queue (queue will not block)
  //    - consumer has to handle emptiness of the queue (queue will not block)
  //
  // Safety: The queue is thread safe if the given conditions are met because the two separate threads changes 
  //         different pointers (push writeIndx and pop readIndx). Although they read both indexes in functions isFull()
  //         and isEmpty(), the evaluation is "conservative", that is, in worst case works well.
  // 
  // Counting: Counting elements is not possible in a not blocking and still thread safe way. For example
  //           a counter as member variable would have to be changed by both, push and pop. And a function
  //           computing the count using writeIndx and readIndx is not achievable, mainly because of the circular 
  //           nature of the queue: the function would need to use module (%) operation which may provide a nonsense 
  //           value if some of the counters change during the computation.
  //
  // Blocking with a counting semaphore: If blocking is required, that is the producer gets blocked when the queue is full
  //          and the consumer when the queue is empty. Then it can be implemented efficiently using a counting semaphore
  //          that reflects the number of elements in the queue. Then push will increase the semaphore (release) and the pop
  //          decrement it (wait). This solution provides the counter of elements (from the semaphore) and allow using 
  //          the N element of the storage instead of only N-1 (checking pointers is unnecessary)
  // 
  // multiple producers or consumers or both: if is needed to have multiple producers or multiple consumers or both, then
  //          a mutex for write and a mutex for read would allow that. Having a unique mutex for both operation is quite 
  //          inefficient, it would block in many unnecessary situations, for example the queue is almost empty but a producer
  //          pushing one elemnt blocks the queue for any reader.
  //
  // (*) disclaimer: it was difficult for me to find good information about the subject in internet, as an example I had to change
  //          the code of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#Circular_buffer_mechanics (so modification
  //          at 10:30 on 13 May 2023 Elxala, comes from me, that is same source as this code, be aware!)
  //          Also, as curiosity, a discussion with chatGPT about this queue provide wrong answers from chatGPT (not the version ChatGPT4).
  //          So, with that said, do not take the code and the notes as the truth but just as my strong opinion.
  //          If any of these notes requires correction, feedback would be appreciated.
  //
  template<typename T, int const N>
  class TNQueue
  {
  protected:
      
      int storage [N];    // Note: N-1 is the actual capacity, see isFull method
      int writeIndx;
      int readIndx;

  public:
     
     TNQueue ():
        writeIndx (0),
        readIndx (0)
     {
     }
     
     bool isFull ()
     {
        return (writeIndx + 1) % N == readIndx;
     }

     bool isEmpty ()
     {
        return readIndx == writeIndx;
     }

     bool push (T item) 
     {
        if (isFull ()) return false;
        
        storage[writeIndx] = item;
        writeIndx = (writeIndx + 1) % N;
        return true;
     }

     bool pop (T & item)
     {
        if (isEmpty ()) return false;
        item = storage[readIndx];
        readIndx = (readIndx + 1) % N;
        return true;
     }
  };

  int main ()
  {
    TNQueue<int, 15> cua;
    
    // basic test
    //
    int value = 1001;
    while (cua.push (value ++));
    while (cua.pop (value))
       printf ("read %d\n", value);
    return 0;
  }
```