# Lockfree standard collections and tutorial or articles

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, locking, thread-safety, lock-free

Does someone know of a good resource for the implementation (meaning source code) of lock-free usual data types. I'm thinking of Lists, Queues and so on?

Locking implementations are extremely easy to find but I can't find examples of lock free algorithms and how to exactly does CAS work and how to use it to implement those structures.

Comment: Not really, I've added the tag though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Julian M Bucknall's blog.  He describes (in detail) lock-free implementations of queues, lists, stacks, etc.

http://www.boyet.com/Articles/LockfreeQueue.html

http://www.boyet.com/Articles/LockfreeStack.html

Comment: I think he assumes garbage collection, however.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.liblfds.org

Written in C.

Answer (score 2):

If C++ is okay with you, take a look at [boost::lockfree](http://tim.klingt.org/git?p=boost_lockfree.git). It has lock-free Queue, Stack, and Ringbuffer implementations.

In the `boost::lockfree::details` section, you'll find a lock-free freelist and tagged pointer (ABA prevention) implementation. You will also see examples of explicit memory ordering via [boost::atomic](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/) (an in-development version of C++0x `std::atomic`).

Both `boost::lockfree` and `boost::atomic` are not part of `boost` yet, but both have seen attention from the boost-development mailing list and are on the schedule for review.

Comment: The link to boost::lockfree is broken