# Python multithreaded extension - thread lock recovery

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a multithreaded C extension for Python. It outputs data to the class in Python using 3 threads.

I am using PyGILState_Ensure / PyGILState_Release API to sync interpreter calls.

There are possible cases in the extension where some threads stuck and get terminated before they call PyGILState_Release.

Is there anyway I can remove that invalid ThreadState and continue using threading API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how you terminate your threads, but in the implementation I have in my head, you would be destructing a thread object would you not? In this case you release the lock in the destructor...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to change the pattern of interaction between threads.

Your current implementation seems to work like this:

```
PyGILState_Ensure();
result = doDangerousThing(); // this could kill the thread
storeToPythonObject(result);
PyGILState_Release();
```

Variant A, obvious:

```
result = doDangerousThing(); // this could kill the thread
PyGILState_Ensure();
storeToPythonObject(result);
PyGILState_Release();
```

Variant B, less obvious, see [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645326/non-blocking-thread-safe-queue-in-c), [[2]](http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/208801974) for ideas:

```
/* worker_thread.c */
result = doDangerousThing(); // this could kill the thread
putToLocklessQueue(result, *queue_in_main_thread);

/* main_thread.c */
if (hasItems(my_lockless_queue)) {
  PyGILState_Ensure();
  while (hasItems(my_lockless_queue)) {
    storeToPythonObject(popItem(my_lockless_queue));
  }
  PyGILState_Release();
  // sleep again here
}
```